# ASP MVC - Can I combine authorization attributes with conditional logic?

Tags: html, forms, request, payload

I know that I can do this to demand both authorizations (AND):

```
    [AdminAuthorize, OtherAuthorize]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
```

...but how do I specify an OR combination (so that at least one of the autorizations is required to pass)?
I guess I could go with writing my own Authorization attribute, but can I avoid this?
A `[AdminAuthorize || OtherAuthorize]` would be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go around this is to generate a base controller with protected methods and no autorization attributes and let two other authorized classes inherit it and call its protected actions.